# Node GET request: Cannot GET Error

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Below is my GET request:

http://localhost:3000/signIn/jDGqIUn6OoHohUND8h/ewaZvtfqnI8VdgXInLmDHt9J9aHuN4NjDjXENLtJjaeHiupTmOWmgPgfRU1y8KCaUWXC9XNoSmNwJF6D/zkJJiZfrZxe/128tPAPC/ItlpQXWScTX4uL7rAiFh1M

Below is the response with the 404 status:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <pre>Cannot GET /signIn/jDGqIUn6OoHohUND8h/ewaZvtfqnI8VdgXInLmDHt9J9aHuN4NjDjXENLtJjaeHiupTmOWmgPgfRU1y8KCaUWXC9XNoSmNwJF6D/zkJJiZfrZxe/128tPAPC/ItlpQXWScTX4uL7rAiFh1M</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is my token too long for the GET request?
What do I do to change the length limit of the GET request in Node or Express?

Comment: Your route has a `/` after the `8h` that you may not be aware of. That route matches `/signIn/{token1}/{token2}`. I expect you have a route such as `signIn/{token1}` you are trying to match.

Comment: Your token contains special character and, maybe, you must encode your URI before make the GET request with this parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot that will do.

Comment: I just forgot urlencode.